# Explain Quantum Entanglement experiment expected outcomes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I'm looking for some help understanding quantum entanglement experiments and expected vs actual outcomes.

We have pairs of spin entangled particles separated by large distance (so $2$ locations). The spin of these particles is "indefinite" or unknown, Now I decide to start measuring at one location. I place my detector rotated $60^\circ$ from the vertical, and I start measuring. After a number of measurements I find that $50\text{%}$ of the time I detect the spin aligned with my detector (spin up), and $50\text{%}$ of the time anti-aligned (spin down).

So my question is this, is there anything that someone can do at the 2nd location with the other half of the paired particles, that would affect my outcomes (at the first location) such that I do not get a $50/50$ measurement? For instance, before each of my measure measurements, my partner measures the corresponding paired particle with a detector in the vertical direction. How does that or affect my outcomes?

**Edit** : Alternatively, how do Quantum Mechanics experimental results imply a "spooky action at a distance" and where do the results differ from hidden variable theory, and how to reproduce those? What is up is up for example with this chart?

> [image]
>
> Source: [Quantum Entanglement: Spooky Action at a Distance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFozGfxmi8A&t=748s), Don Lincoln, Fermilab YouTube channel (12 February 2020), 12:48.

Answer (score 1):

> is there anything that someone can do at the 2nd location with the other half of the paired particles that would affect my outcomes at the first location?

**No.** There is no action you can do to the second particle that will affect the measurement results of the first one.

Entanglement is a form of *correlation*. The only way to observe it is to take measurements on both particles, communicate them (using classical, slower-than-light communications) to a central location (which can be at either site), and look at how the two experiments correlate with each other.

Entanglement is weird ("spooky") because, if you assume that the results of the experiments are produced by any arbitrary Local Hidden Variables model (i.e. each particle has a (classical) "state", and they're not allowed to communicate), then there are some measures of correlation (like e.g. the [CHSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality) measure) for which you can prove strict bounds on the amount of correlation possible, and the quantum mechanical results exceed those bounds.

However, that can only be seen afterwards, once the results have been collected in a single place and compared with each other. Without that step of classical communication, the particles are completely independent.

Comment: I guess I'm unclear with what the correlations are and what interpretation of them leads us to believe this is not due to local hidden variables. Its as if everyone forgets to include the punchline in a joke. Perhaps see my edit to the original question. What correlation happens, and why would we assume that this is not due to some prior 'hidden' state?

Comment: Because there is a theorem, known as [Bell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem), that limits the amount of (a certain type of) correlation that can be observed inside a Local Hidden Variables theory. Nobody "forgot" the "punchline" (and physics is not a "joke") -- if you want the details, they're in every textbook on the matter. If all you consume is simplified descriptions, though, then of course you will only ever see simplified descriptions.

Comment: I'm aware of Bells theorem, but yes looking for an explanation or at least part of one. For example, since both Quantum Entanglement and hidden variable theory allow in a sense for the particles to be 'correlated' in a sense (hidden variable theory says they have a hidden property for example) , it is unclear to me why the predictions are different. I in no way think physics is a joke, just disappointed in some explanations I've seen (also see the other answer on this page which basically treated the question as a joke).

Comment: The predictions are different because the theories are different, down to their very bones. If you want more details, there's no shortcut -- you have to start with a proper textbook.

Answer (score -1):

*is there anything that someone can do at the 2nd location with the other half of the paired particles, that would effect my outcomes (at the first location) such that I do not get a 50/50 measurement*.

Yes.  He can measure the paired particle at his location, then load that particle into a weapon and propel it toward your laboratory, where it destroys (or recalibrates) your measurement apparatus. But of course he doesn't need quantum mechanics for that.  Your question shouldn't be "Is there anything he can do...?", it should be "Is there anything he can do using quantum mechanics that he  can't do **without** using quantum mechanics?".  The answer to that one is No.

Comment: lol, good one. Ok so then please explain how Quantum Mechanics experimental results implies a "spooky action at a distance" and where the results differ from hidden variable theory. For example in this video, see the chart at the end: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFozGfxmi8A&t=777s which unfortunately the video totally glosses over.

Comment: @Fraggle because the two particles are spatially separated. Any hidden variables  would have to be nonlocal. Entanglement occurs regardless of distance. The Bell experiments show any hidden variable theory must be nonlocal to match the observed correlations in measurement outcomes, no matter how far the particles separated.